# delphi - count duplicates in list and sort

Tags: delphi, duplicates, tstringlist

I need count string duplicates and after sort them by DESC
example:

stringlist

```
111
222
333
111
222
111
```

I need to get

```
111(3)
222(2)
333(1)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What specific problem are you having doing this yourself? What effort have you made to do so?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty easy to do with a `TStringList`.  Sort it first as needed, and then loop through it counting repeating strings, eg:

```pascal
var
  List: TStringList;
  Dups: TStringList;
  I, Count: Integer;
  StrToCompare, StrItem: string;
begin
  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    List.Add('111');
    List.Add('222');
    List.Add('333');
    List.Add('111');
    List.Add('222');
    List.Add('111');

    List.Sort; // or List.CustomSort() if needed

    Dups := TStringList.Create;
    try
      StrToCompare := List[0];
      Count := 1;

      for I := 1 to List.Count-1 do
      begin
        StrItem := List[I];
        if StrItem <> StrToCompare then
        begin
          Dups.Add(Format('%s(%d)', [StrToCompare, Count]));
          StrToCompare := StrItem;
          Count := 1;
        end else
          Inc(Count);
      end;

      Dups.Add(Format('%s(%d)', [StrToCompare, Count]));

      // use Dups as needed...

    finally
      Dups.Free;
    end;
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;
```